# Need to display multiple json image arrays but only one ever does

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, iteration, jquery-cycle2

So it must be an iteration thing that Im not getting! I have a for loop in my template file which displays multiple cycle2 slideshows:

```
<?php foreach ($foo as $bar) { ?>

    <div class="image">
        <a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">
            <div class="cycle-slideshow"
                data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
                data-cycle-timeout=0
                data-cycle-swipe=true
                >
                <div class="cycle-prev"></div>
                <div class="cycle-next"></div>
                <img class="productID_<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="Click to see more details on <?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Now originally I had this working on mouseenter so it did it for each .image in the for loop. Now Im fiddling with it to load all the images on ready. This is what I have so far but it only loads the first array of images for every instance of the cycle2 slideshows.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var image = $(".cycle-slideshow").find("img:first");
    var classList = image.prop('class').split(/\s+/);
    $.each( classList, function(index, item){
        if( item.indexOf('productID_') > -1 ) {
            product_id = item.replace("productID_","");

            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=product/product/images',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'product_id='+product_id + '&width='+image.width() + '&height='+image.height(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    if (json['images']) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < json['images'].length; i++) { 
                            image.after('<img src="'+json['images'][i]+'" width="'+image.width()+'" height="'+image.height()+'" alt="'+$(image).prop("alt")+'" />');
                        }

                        image.parent().cycle();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Ive tried all sorts with this line:

```
var image = $(".cycle-slideshow").find("img:first");
```

Like using .children and img:eq(0), however the above works best with the image size parameters being brought in correctly.

But how to iterate so each instance of cycle2 lists its own json array?

Any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT for clarification on answer below to see if it helps:

```
public function images() {
    $json = array();
    if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $product_images = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($this->request->post['product_id']);
        if ($product_images) {                      
            $this->load->model('tool/image');
            foreach ($product_images as $result) {
                if(($result['image'] && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $result['image'])) && isset($this->request->post['width']) && isset($this->request->post['height'])){
                    $json['images'][] =  $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->request->post['width'], $this->request->post['height']);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cycle-slideshow").each(function() {
        var image = $(this).find("img:first");
        // Rest of your code
    });
});
```

Your code just sets `image` to the first image in the first slideshow, and never processes the other slideshows.

Other suggestions:

Put the product ID in a `data-` attribute, so you don't have to extract it from the class.

Use the following syntax in your AJAX call:

```
data: {
    product_id: product_id,
    width: image.width(),
    height: image.height()
}
```

Comment: That was quick and awesome! OK so I used your first bit of code...I knew I had to use an each I just wasnt getting the placement/syntax. Im a JS/Jquery noob.

Perhaps I should expand on the rest of the code as I tried the data- bit you posted and the image sizing got all screwed up. Im using the code above in a controller file...see edit.

Comment: I must say I dont really understand whats going on with the sizes but with your data- changes I get: iphone_2-44x16.jpg instead of: iphone_2-271x271.jpg

Comment: I'm not changing the actual data being sent, my change to the `data:` parameter just tells jQuery to format it for you. It ensures everything is encoded properly, since you forgot to call `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: Ahh OK yes I can see that my image sizing is still screwed up. Its fine on the first array of images but after that the sizing is tiny and then stretched. Doh. Need to look into it. But thanks for your help dude.